# Can we control the Bandwidth for webrtc Screensharing

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, screensharing

I am familiar with webrtc bandwidth control for video streams. I am able to specify maximum bandwidth for video steams(P2P connections). But when I tried to set max bitrate i.e. specify the bandwidth for screen sharing P2P connection I am getting following error.

`Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Read-only field modified in setParameters().`

For code reference I am using following method for bandwidth

`'RTCRtpSender' in window`

`'setParameters' in window.RTCRtpSender.prototype`

I just want to know if we can control the bandwidth of screen share over webrtc or I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance

Chetan

Comment: This is a bit old, but for me it did *kind of* work by looping through all of the senders and setting the bandwidth after receiving an offer/answer. Not a very good solution in my opinion, though.